# Embedding IronPython and overwriting Environment Variables

Tags: c#, environment-variables, ironpython

I embed an IronPython interpreter in a C# application to execute a Python script. The script evaluates a specific environment variable `VAR1` using `os.environ['VAR1']`

I need to change the value of `VAR1` temporarily before the script is executed. To do this I call

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VAR1", "NEW_VALUE");
```

in the C# code. Unfortunately this does not work. The Python script still "sees" the old value of `VAR1` (the value it had when the hosting C# application started).

Here is a complete example code:

```
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("VAR1", "NEW_VALUE");
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        engine.SetSearchPaths(new string[] { @"c:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\" });
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        engine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(ms, Encoding.Unicode);

        var script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import os\nprint os.environ['VAR1']");
        script.Execute();

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
```

My understanding is that the IronPython engine runs in the same process as the C# host application. If this is correct, how can the Python code and the C# code see different environment variables?

Is there a better (working) way to set an environment variable for the Python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know why the above code doesn't work but one can simply set an environment variable in the Python environment by executing Python code that sets the variable *BEFORE* executing the real code:

```
engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import os\nos.environ['VAR1'] = 'NEW_VALUE'").Execute();
var CodeIReallyWantToRun = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(...);
CodeIReallyWantToRun.Execute();
```